# write on sd card! Android, txt data

Tags: java, android, inputstream, outputstream

I always get following log when I start my App:

```
12-17 14:52:02.688: E/ThrottleService(287): problem during onPollAlarm: java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I start an intent from my Main Activity but before I do:

```
Charakter ch = new Charakter(MainActivity.this,1, 2);
```

then the starting method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Charakteruebersicht.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Here the charakteruebersicht clas:

```
public class Charakteruebersicht extends Activity{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.charakteruebersicht);
    TextView CT= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tVCharakter);
    Charakter ch = new Charakter(Charakteruebersicht.this, 0, 0);
    Item it;
    Waffen waf = new Waffen();
    Rüstungen rüs = new Rüstungen();
    int waffe=waf.gibItem(ch.getaktuellerWaffenindex(Charakteruebersicht.this)).getWaffenschaden();
    int ruestung=rüs.gibItem(ch.getaktuellerRüstungsindex(Charakteruebersicht.this)).getRüstungswert();
    Log.d("Waffe", String.valueOf(waffe));
    Log.d("Rüstung", String.valueOf(ruestung));
    CT.setText("Der aktuelle Waffenschaden beträgt"+waffe +"!  Der aktuelle Rüstungswert beträgt:" +ruestung );[..]
```

Here one write and read void:

```
private int leseWaffenindex(Context ct2) {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    File filesDir= new File(ct2.getCacheDir()+"/"+ "Waffen.txt");
     String datax = "0" ;
        try {

            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream (filesDir) ;
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader ( fIn ) ;
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader ( isr ) ;

            String readString = buffreader.readLine ( ) ;
            while ( readString != null ) {
                datax =  readString ;
                readString = buffreader.readLine ( ) ;
            }

            isr.close ( ) ;
        } catch ( IOException ioe ) {
            ioe.printStackTrace ( ) ;
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(datax);
    }
private void writeWaffe(Context ct2, int aktuellerWaffenindex2) {
     File Meinspeicherort = new File(ct2.getCacheDir()+"/"+"Waffen.txt");
     BufferedWriter out=null;
     try {
        Meinspeicherort.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Meinspeicherort));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
     try {

            out.write ( aktuellerWaffenindex2 ) ;
            out.flush ( ) ;


        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace ( ) ;
        }finally
        {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
       }
    }
```

Comment: I would advise you from now on to write your code in english. There are many reasons to do it, one of them being - in the event that you need help, it would be a lot(if not at all) easier for others to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Ah okay, i understand you sorry ;)! i hope this is okay, because that are only some variables and datanames which are on german ;)

Comment: Could you add comments next to the function names etc of them in english :) I know a little german but not enougth :P

Comment: I suppose the logged error has nothing to do with the code you are showing us. Does your app work?

Comment: The app works not really, always when i started the intent the app frooze....

Comment: The posted error is not a direct result of your code, but rather a mistake in system code.  However, your app's startup process may be excessively slow, triggering buggy system monitoring code.  On Android you need to move any time consuming operations off the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to open a file located in the system folder. Instead you should be trying to create a file either on the SDCard or within the local storage directory for your application.

Please read this to help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html